# WCF service types with same type name, same XSD namespace

Tags: xml, wcf, web-services, soap, xsd

I have a WCF service method that I want to expose.

The service method parameter type is base class of all types that have the same class name, and XML namespace.

All derived types are in different C# name spaces, but must be exposed in the same xml namespace. Below is the implementation.

However, error occurred when trying to add service reference saying duplicate Shape type.

Ideally, Visual studio should auto-assign a C# namespace for the second Shape (e.g. Set1.Shape, Set2.Shape). So it can download all types.

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IShape
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Set1.Shape))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Set2.Shape))]
    void GetShape(ShapeBase shape);
}

public class ShapeBase : IShape { }

//Example only. 
namespace Set1
{
    public class Shape : ShapeBase { }   
}

namespace Set2
{
    public class Shape : ShapeBase { }
}
```

**Update**

I am able to publish them on WCF service side, which makes one think the reason it cannot do the same on client side, is because WSDL does NOT support name space in programming language like C#.

Answer (score 0):

Each type must have unique combination of XML namespace and XML name. So if your types must be in the same XML namespace they must have different element name. Currently they most probably don't have because CLR type name is the same.

Comment: CLR type name is the same but they are in different name space. It might be because WSDL does NOT support C# name space, or wcf client has no information on when to assign a different name space.

Comment: By default CLR namespace is used to create XML namespace but it would result in different XML namespaces for each class which is something you mentioned as not an option. Once you redefine XML namespace, CLR namespace is not used any more.

Answer (score 0):

As Ladislav said, you need to have different node names inside of the same XML namespace. You can attribute this by using the DataContractAttribute's Name property:

```
namespace Set1
{
    [DataContract(Name="Set1Shape")]
    public class Shape : ShapeBase { }   
}

namespace Set2
{
    [DataContract(Name="Set2Shape")]
    public class Shape : ShapeBase { }
}
```

Comment: I knew that. Must have the same published type name, and same xml namespace. Your advice has different published type name.

Comment: @Pingpong: That requirement is not possible to achieve. Deserialization will not know which type to use.

Comment: The only way to expose a type across a XML web-service boundary is by XML namespace combined with the root node name of the type. This *defines* the type which you are exposing. What you are asking to do is not logical. There is nothing else which can indicate that the types are not the same. Hence the error message you get telling you that.